# how to delete old account and credit card info by

Tags: google-play-store, google

How do you delete some one else's account off your Android phones play store there is no credit card on it but it makes me have to go and find me and then I can see my info if not it goes to the lady I bought my phone from

Answer (score 0):

*Settings > Accounts > Google* then select the account which you wish to remove.

*Settings > Accounts > Google >  select the account which you wish to remove > More  > Remove account*.

PS: You'll need to stop Syncing first.

On older versions (1.5 > 2.3.5) there is no way to remove an account, only by resetting the device to the factory settings.

Comment: In older versions, there's no *official* way. De facto, there is one which is a bit tricky. You don't need a full factory reset, but just delete data from the corresponding Google apps. But of course that also means all accounts would be dropped – no way to drop a single account only there.

Comment: Exactly, but the account will still be present in the phone.

Comment: No. But this is not a discussion area, and apart from that, the percentage of users interested in that an old Android version is rather low :) Which is why I didn't post the complete procedure.